# Структура таблиц SQL и выборка данных

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть такая структура таблиц:

**path**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**destination**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**destination_edge**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

destination - это как вершины графа (ориентированного), destination_edge - грани

**path_destination_edge**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь хранятся последовательности маршрутов path, при этом:

- position 0 dest_from это точка отправления
- position max dest_to это точка прибытия
- при этом может быть всего одна запись, то есть position будет 0

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT
    path.id as "Path ID",
    sum(de.distance) as "Full distance (km)",
    string_agg(concat(dFrom.name, ' - ', dTo.name), '; ') as "Path"

from path

join path_destination_edge pde on path.id = pde.path_id
join destination_edge de on de.id = pde.destination_edge_id
join destination dFrom on dFrom.id = de.destination_from_id
join destination dTo on dTo.id = de.destination_to_id

group by path.id
```

Его результат вот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу заменить path на destinationFrom и destinationTo, то есть из:

```
Path: [Vladimir - Moscow (Kievsky); Moscow (Kievsky) - Saint-Petersburg (Moskowsky)]
```

Нужно получить:

```
Destinaton From: [Vladimir]
Destination To: [Saint-Petersburg (Moskowsky)]
```

Если псевдокодом, то это что-то вроде
Destination From: "get destination.name from destination_edge.from where path_destination_edge.position = 0"
Destination To: "get destination.name from destination_edge.to where path_destination_edge.position = MAX(position)"

Итак, вопрос в том, можно ли сделать такое, и правильно ли сделана структура в целом, а то как-то не клеится.

Comment: Замените скриншоты исходных данных на online fiddle (в крайнем случае - на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скрипты). Покажите результат строго для предоставленных данных в формате таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>(Прежде всего поддержу коллегу @Akina: набирать все ваши данные
руками было непросто.)</sup>

Может быть, можно как-то без подзапросов,
да и оптимизировать местами наверняка можно, но скорее всего
копать вам в сторону чего-то такого:

```sql
WITH paths AS (
  SELECT path.id
       , FIRST_VALUE(dFrom.name) OVER path_window AS from_name
       , LAST_VALUE(dTo.name) OVER path_window AS to_name
       , de.distance
       , CONCAT(dFrom.name, ' - ', dTo.name) AS path
    FROM path
         INNER JOIN path_destination_edge AS pde
                 ON path.id = pde.path_id
         INNER JOIN destination_edge AS de
                 ON de.id = pde.destination_edge_id
         INNER JOIN destination AS dFrom
                 ON dFrom.id = de.destination_from_id
         INNER JOIN destination AS dTo
                 ON dTo.id = de.destination_to_id
  WINDOW path_window AS (
           PARTITION BY path.id
               ORDER BY pde.position
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                 AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
         )
   ORDER BY path.id ASC
       , pde.position ASC
)
SELECT id AS "Path ID"
     , from_name AS "From"
     , to_name AS "To"
     , SUM(distance) AS "Full distance (km)"
     , STRING_AGG(path, '; ') as "Path"
  FROM paths
 GROUP BY id
     , from_name
     , to_name
 ORDER BY id
;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h458V7hNQLrNRWkmyzecUC/0).

[Про оконные функции](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-window.html).

Comment: Прошу прощения за скриншоты, даже не надеялся что кто-то будет это руками набирать)
Большое спасибо за помощь, то что нужно.